# Facing an error while trying to boot windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, partition, windows, dual-boot

i have been facing a problem lately. I wanted to create a partition of 100 GB on ubuntu only. Which i did but then for some reason i have been facing this error while trying to boot windows 10. the windows 10 partition was installed on dev/sda1 i think and then moved to dev/sda2 and i have no idea how did this happen. i'm not sure though but if someone could help me i would be really thankful.I messed up. :)

```
error: no such device: DACA5761CA573949.
error: no such partition. 
error: no such partition.
Press any key to continue...
```

while in the grub menu windows details are like this `windows 10 (on dev/sda1)`

and then i checked the details of the partition from disks (ubuntu). These were the details.

```
    Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda2          1126400  519921663 518795264 247.4G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        519921664 1236719615 716797952 341.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       1236721662 1953523711 716802050 341.8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       1236721664 1717561343 480839680 229.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       1951526912 1953523711   1996800   975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       1912563712 1951512575  38948864  18.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       1717563392 1912561663 194998272    93G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

[image]
[image]
[image]

FileSystem Partition 2 266 GB NTFS is where windows is installed mounted at dev/sda2

Comment: Try holding shift while booting to see if you get a menu https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

Comment: well i do get the grub menu where i choose the OS i want to run. Ubuntu OS works fine but windows 10 doesn't at all just gives and error: no such device. and i takes me back to the grub menu

Comment: ah hmm, as far as I know, grub relies on a tool call `os-prober` to locate and create boot entries for windows and other os's. I have not used it in particular before. I would try `sudo update-grub` and reboot once; but it is likely not going to change anything. 
maybe check `sudo /usr/bin/os-prober` to make sure we're finding the partition with windows correctly. I read just now that mixing UEFI and non-uefi windows/linux won't generally work, you don't think you've mixed uefi and non-uefi do you?
Check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204783/os-prober-not-finding-windows

Comment: i added a new screenshot above. it is giving a red exclamation mark

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I noticed in your screenshots that the partition table is a MBR type, can you check if the system is booted as uefi with: `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` i think you must to be using a BIOS bootloader, however if you are using UEFI then i worry that you might have installed windows in legacy mode, and ubuntu in uefi mode which I don't think can be compatible

Comment: Maybe but windows 10 and ubuntu both were working fine together till yesterday , is there a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

~I think you are inflicted by a common UEFI problem Windows inflicted upon itself. ~

Window distributors often ignore the Intel UEFI specification and wrote motherboard firmware which hard-coded a single bootloader named `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`.

Normally any files in EFI/ should be options to boot, for example `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`, however I don't think any "Windows 10 Certified" motherboards follow the Intel specification, they all seem to hard code for windows-only.

A common hack is to overwrite `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` with the linux bootloader `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`. This forces the motherboard to boot linux always since only one os can have a bootloader on each drive.

This is okay because the Linux bootloader is capable of offering a boot menu that can let the user choose to boot windows or linux. This hack+menu works around motherboard's and windows's limitations.

This GRUB menu can be hidden during boot. There may be a pause at a black screen, this is often a few seconds where the bootloader waits for a hot key to activate and show it before contuning to boot linux. The hey key has changed a few times recently, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time

There can be another problem where some motherboards don't turn on the keyboard before loading the bootloader. If the keyboard is off the GRUB menu cannot be activated or used. Be sure your keyboard lights up before the os boots, and if it doesn't try to disable "fast boot" in bios.

To get to the bios settings, use `sudo systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`. You can also reconfigure grub and reboot to see if it shows up: https://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-at-the-beginning-of-boot

Edit: the screenshots say this is an MBR partition table, which TMK isn't supported with UEFI

Comment: thank you for your response, but the grub menu does appears and ubuntu works fine but windows 10 wont boot.

Comment: error: no such device: DACA5761CA573949.
error: no such partition. 
error: no such partition.
Press any key to continue...

Comment: and when i press enter to continue it takes me back to grub boot menu.